# Reading a csv file with millions of row via java as fast as possible

Tags: java, csv

I want to read a csv files including millions of rows and use the attributes for my decision Tree algorithm. My code is below:

```
String csvFile = "myfile.csv";
List<String[]> rowList = new ArrayList();
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
String encoding = "UTF-8";
BufferedReader br2 = null;
try {
    int counterRow = 0;
    br2 =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFile), encoding));
    while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null) { 
        line=line.replaceAll(",,", ",NA,");
        String[] object = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        rowList.add(object); 
        counterRow++;
    }
    System.out.println("counterRow is: "+counterRow);
    for(int i=1;i<rowList.size();i++){
        try{
           //this method includes many if elses only.
           ImplementDecisionTreeRulesFor2012(rowList.get(i)[0],rowList.get(i)[1],rowList.get(i)[2],rowList.get(i)[3],rowList.get(i)[4],rowList.get(i)[5],rowList.get(i)[6]); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
           System.out.printlnt("Exception occurred");   
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("fix"+ex);
}
```

It is working fine when the size of the csv file is not large. However, it is large indeed. Therefore I need another way to read a csv faster. Is there any advice? Appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You use two hidden regexes in a row (`replaceAll` and `split`). Since your CSV is that simple, I suggest you use a splitter, like [Guava's `Splitter`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html), which does the job really as expected (unlike `split` which has a lot of issues). Also, despite it being simple, how can you be sure that your method `ImplementDecisionTreeRulesFor2012` isn't the root cause of your slowness?

Comment: Maybe a library can suit your needs. I see there is a comparison here : https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison

Comment: Why do you need 2 loops and `rowList` to support them? Why not have a single loop that reads in a line and passes it on to `ImplementDecisionTreeRulesFor2012` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this snippet I see two issues which will slow you down considerably:

```
while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null) { 
    line=line.replaceAll(",,", ",NA,");
    String[] object = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    rowList.add(object); 
    counterRow++;
}
```

First, rowList starts with the default capacity and will have to be increased many times, always causing a copy of the old underlying array to the new.

Worse, however, ist the excessive blow-up of the data into a String[] object. You'll need the columns/cells only when you call ImplementDecisionTreeRulesFor2012 *for that row* - not all the time while you read that file and process all the other rows. Move the split (or something better, as suggested by comments) to the second row.

(Creating many objects is bad, even if you can afford the memory.)

Perhaps it would be better to call ImplementDecisionTreeRulesFor2012 while you read the "millions"? It would avoid the rowList ArrayList altogether.

**Later**
Postponing the split reduces the execution time for 10 million rows
from 1m8.262s (when the program ran out of heap space) to 13.067s.

If you aren't forced to read all rows before you can call Implp...2012, the time reduces to 4.902s.

**Finally** writing the split and replace by hand:

```
String[] object = new String[7];
//...read...
    String x = line + ",";
    int iPos = 0;
    int iStr = 0; 
    int iNext = -1;
    while( (iNext = x.indexOf( ',', iPos )) != -1 && iStr < 7 ){
        if( iNext == iPos ){
            object[iStr++] = "NA";
        } else {
             object[iStr++] = x.substring( iPos, iNext );
        }
        iPos = iNext + 1;
    }
    // add more "NA" if rows can have less than 7 cells
```

reduces the time to 1.983s. This is about 30 times faster than the original code, which runs into OutOfMemory anyway.

Comment: How have you done your timings? If you're reading from disk there's a good chance that after the first time you run it the file could be in the file cache in the OS

Comment: I forgot to add that the *original* code ran out of heap space after more than one minute (see edit). This isn't an issue of the time required for reading a file.

Comment: Are you totally sure about that? I'd probably want to flush the cache inbetween runs just to be totally sure

Comment: You might want to bring `new String[7]` outside of the line-loop. And maybe add a check on `iStr` in case a line has more than 7 fields.

Comment: @tddmonkey You might try it yourself, use 2000000 rows so you see some effect.

Answer (score 13):

Just use [uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers)' CSV parser instead of trying to build your custom parser. Your implementation will probably not be fast or flexible enough to handle all corner cases.

It is extremely memory efficient and you can parse a million rows in less than a second. [This link](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) has a performance comparison of many java CSV libraries and univocity-parsers comes on top.

Here's a simple example of how to use it:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); // you'll find many options here, check the tutorial.
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

// parses all rows in one go (you should probably use a RowProcessor or iterate row by row if there are many rows)
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new File("/path/to/your.csv"));
```

BUT, that loads everything into memory. To stream all rows, you can do this:

```
String[] row;
parser.beginParsing(csvFile)
while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
    //process row here.
}
```

The faster approach is to use a [RowProcessor](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/tree/master/src/main/java/com/univocity/parsers/common/processor), it also gives more flexibility:

```
settings.setRowProcessor(myChosenRowProcessor);
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
parser.parse(csvFile);
```

Lastly, it has built-in [routines](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/univocity/parsers/common/routine/AbstractRoutines.java) that use the parser to perform some common tasks (iterate java beans, dump `ResultSet`s, etc)

This should cover the basics, check the documentation to find the best approach for your case.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: I tried using this and it is taking lot of time to load the csv file.

Comment: The `parseAll` method loads everything in memory. You should actually use `beginParsing`, then `parseNext` to iterate over the results, or simply define a `RowProcessor` then call `parse`. This will NOT load everything in memory. I'll update my answer to show an example.

Comment: by increasing the heapsize,univocity works fine.However,I don't see univocity very helpful while we try to parse multiple csv files concurrently.Advise me please if I Am wrong here.

Comment: @sskumar you can parse a 5TB file with less than 50MB of heap size. You are definitely doing something wrong such as storing large chunks of data in memory, or using convenience features (such as getting lists of rows) that inherently store everything in memory but are only suitable for small datasets.

Comment: I am curious to walk through the rows upon the completion of parsing.I should be able to get control over each and every row and my software need to deal with that.Mere parsing of csv file less than 50MB heapsize is impossible I can say with univocity so far.

Comment: @sskumar86 if you are storing all rows you will run into memory issues no matter what parser you use. Try creating an ArrayList containing 10 million string arrays and with non-repeated content in each one of them to see what I mean. There's no magic solution for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeronimo.With the JVM heap size topup,I was able to achieve the csv extraction as I wished.I really liked the feature of ignoring columns while filtering the wished columns in a csv.

Comment: @JeronimoBackes , can we customize the return type as i cannot find this in documentation. I don't need the List<String> but i want each row as List<double [ ] > so if you know it could be done in Univocity.

Answer (score 1):

on top of the aforementioned univocity it's worth checking

- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv
- http://simpleflatmapper.org/0101-getting-started-csv.html, it also have a low level api that by pass the String creation.

the 3 of them would as the time of the comment the fastest csv parser.

Chance is that writting your own parser would be slower and buggy.

Comment: There's a performance comparison here: https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison

Answer (score 0):

If you're aiming for objects (i.e. data-binding), I've written a high-performance library [sesseltjonna-csv](https://github.com/skjolber/sesseltjonna-csv) you might find interesting. Benchmark comparison with SimpleFlatMapper and uniVocity [here](https://github.com/skjolber/csv-benchmark).